# How linux Os let applications read from pipe

Tags: linux, shell

I am confused by how linux could let application read from pipe like "cat /etc/hosts | grep 'localhost'". I know in a independent program fork a child and communicate by pipe between each other. But for two independent program communicating by pipe I don't know how. 
In example "cat /etc/hosts | grep 'localhost'" How could Grep know which file descriptor it should read to get the input from "cat /etc/hosts".  Is there a "conventional" pipe provided by OS, to let Grep know where to get the input? I want to know the mechanism behind this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

grep in your example gets it from stdin. It is the shell's responsibility to call `pipe(2)` to create the pipe and then `dup2(2)` in each of the `fork(2)` children to assign their end of the pipe to stdin or stdout before calling one of the `exec(3)` functions to actually run the other executables.

Comment: The important point here is that in the example given, both `cat` and `grep` are child processes of the shell, so they *are* related.

Comment: It's `pipe(2)`, not `mkfifo(3)`, since the pipe in unnamed.